# Options instead of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer

1. I want to color each rows of table, 
          by using particular values of database

   ```
     spcification of mine database is some what like

      **
      id     name    color
      1      pavan   red
      2      xyz     white
      **
   ```
2. i can  give a color to complete table using

   ```
      table.setBackground(new color(158,145,134);       




      please provide me some solution or hint to approch towards answer,
      Thanks in advance.
   ```

Comment: Why do you say it is hard to apply on JTable? Have you checked [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)?

Comment: JXTable (from the SwingX project) has support for Highlighters, and contains an alternate row highlighter by default, making this requirement almost a one-liner

Comment: but can we apply it for each row as per db value thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

This isn't hard at all with a JTable!  In fact, it's incredibly easy!

See my answer here: [Highlight a cell in JTable via custom table model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907714/highlight-a-cell-in-jtable-via-custom-table-model/9910740#9910740)

Reproduced for ease:

---

...Subclass JTable and override [`JTable.preparedRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int%29).  If the `row` and `column` numbers are the same, you can change the background color of the `Component` returned as the display (usually a `JLabel`);

Here's an example that highlights the row the mouse is over:

```
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(final TableCellRenderer renderer, final int row, final int column) {
    final Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    if (row == this.itsRow) {
        c.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    return c;
}
```

where `this.itsRow` is an int field updated by a `MouseMotionListener`:

```
this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            SubclassedJTable.this.itsRow = SubclassedJTable.this.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            SubclassedJTable.this.repaint();
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {/***/}
    });
```

Comment: sir it is necessary to have row and column numbers are the same, to color each row as per db value rply...thanks